# Правильно ли поставлена запятая? ,, Я иду, уставший, тревожный и злой"

Tags: запятые

Пример:
Я иду(?)уставший, тревожный и злой.

Я иду, уставший, тревожный и злой.

Правильно ли поставлена запятая?

Comment: Тревожный человек — тип личности; в ряду определений состояния (уставший, злой) напрашивается «встревоженный».

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Похоже на стихотворный текст, в этом случае учитывается ритмика стиха, скорее всего, это выглядит так:

*Я идУ, // **устАвший, тревОжный и злОй**.*
Оборот, выраженный однородным рядом определений, обособляется. Ударение падает и на глагол, и на оборот.

Для сравнения:

В прозаическом тексте возможен такой вариант:  *Конец дня. Я иду **устАвший // и злОй.***

Ряд определений входит в состав сказуемого и не обособляется (именная часть сказуемого). Связкой будет глагол со значением движения. Ударение падает только на оборот.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Конечно, контекст очень желателен, потому что можно вообразить различные ситуации, но важно следующее.

1. Правила позволяют нам использовать **варианты** при оформлении этой конструкции.  Розенталь http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=109#pp109

**Нет обособления**

Пункт 2. Не обособляются распространенные определения: 3) связанные по смыслу не только с подлежащим, но и со сказуемым, **в состав которого они входят**:  Аккуратный старичок ходил вооружённый дождевым зонтом (М. Г.); Обычно такие конструкции образуются **с глаголами движения** или состояния, выступающими в роли знаменательной связки.

**Обособление**

Пункт 10. Определение, относящееся к личному местоимению, обособляется независимо от степени его распространенности и местоположения:

2. **Выбор варианта.**  Идея **смыслового акцентирования**  на движении лица  или на его состоянии, которая в письменной речи связана с выбором знаков пунктуации, в устной  речи присутствует вполне **реально и наглядно**  – это наличие или отсутствие **ударения** на глаголе, обозначающем это **движение**.

Answer (score 4):

Здесь пунктуация зависит от заложенного *смысла*, прояснить который помог бы контекст.

Вариант 1: имеющиеся прилагательные акцентируют **состояние**, в котором лирический герой передвигается (идет, плетется, едет - не важно), а не факт передвижения, о котором, возможно, уже сказано, и новой информации глагол не несет.

> Пора идти на пятое собеседование за день. Я иду уставший, тревожный и
> злой.

Вариант 2: глагол акцентирует **факт передвижения**, а прилагательные независимо от этого указывают на душевное состояние персонажа (он действительно идет, при этом он уставший и злой).

> -- Рядовой Петров, живо ко мне!
>
> Я иду, уставший, тревожный и злой.

Comment: !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!